# Dictionary not being recognized in Visual Studio/Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, compiler-errors

I am lost here, for some reason I am getting multiple errors from line 10. I am building an app using Xamarin and I am trying to create a dictionary and for some reason, I get the following errors

```
Error   IDE1007 The name 'exerciseTypes.Add' does not exist in the current context.
Error   IDE1007 The name 'exerciseTypes' does not exist in the current context.
Error   IDE1007 The name 'Add' does not exist in the current context.
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Trainer_App
{
    internal class Exercise
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, bool> exerciseTypes = new Dictionary<string, bool> ();
        exerciseTypes.Add("Warmup",false);
        private string name;
        private int min_num_balls;
        private int[] num_participants;
        private string court_type;
        private string[] accessories;
        private static int id = 0;

        public Exercise()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I want the dictionary to be a part of the class and not the Objects

Comment: this is a basic C# issue, it has nothing to do with Xamarin

Comment: Well all I want is to insert data to the dictionary without using a method (because it might be a problem later-on) and without it being object specific (static)

Answer (score 1):

You can't place a method call directly under a class declaration. You could move it inside the constructor though:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Trainer_App
{
    internal class Exercise
    {
        public Dictionary<string, bool> exerciseTypes = new Dictionary<string, bool> ();
        private string name;
        private int min_num_balls;
        private int[] num_participants;
        private string court_type;
        private string[] accessories;
        private static int id = 0;

        public Exercise()
        {
            exerciseTypes.Add("Warmup",false); // Here!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to be a dictionary to be used by the class. after that i want to create a specific dictionary for each object